# How to use foreach inside another foreach in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

from my codes under, i want to set foreach enter another foreach as shown, i have two tables (reservation and courses ), and the objective is to find the status of course who have the same ID in two tables.

Tables:

```
Courses: (id_course, statutCourses)
reservation: (id_reserv, Location, Destination, Date, Phone, price)
```

thanks for helping me

```
@foreach ($reservations as $reservation)
<tr>
  <td> {{ $reservation->id_reserv}}</td>
  <td> {{ $reservation->Location}}</td>
  <td> {{ $reservation->Destination  }}</td>
  <td> {{ $reservation->Date }}</td>
  <td> {{ $reservation->Phone  }}</td>
  <td> {{ $reservation->price }}</td>
  <td> 

    @foreach($courses as $course)
      @if($course->id_course == $reservation->id_reserv)
        <table style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-right: 10px;">Statut :</td>
            <td>{{$course->statutCourses}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      @endif
    @endforeach
  </td> 
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable check this out

Comment: this kind of logic is done in controller (at least)

Comment: What error you facing

Comment: i don't get the data that's the problem. is it possible to make foreach inside foreach using two tables ? if you have an exemple please show me.

Comment: Can you post your relationship between course and reservation, and also your controller for the blade please? Is the expected result to have every course for each reservation? :)